# Assign select value to variable into Execute in PostgreSQL 9.3 function

Tags: postgresql

Consider a function like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(
    string1 character varying    
    )
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
id1 INTEGER;

BEGIN

id1  := (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = string1);
END;
......
```

It works fine and I get the `id1` value for using in other part of the function.

Now, I want to rewrite the function and pass a name who act like identifier of the table.

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(
        string1 character varying,
        tablecode character varying --new argument
        )
      RETURNS integer AS
    $BODY$
    DECLARE
    id1 INTEGER;

    BEGIN
.....
```

And now, there are my attepms for get `id1` value and the errors:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('id1 := (SELECT id FROM %I WHERE mycolumn = %s)', tablecode||'_Conceptos', quote_literal(string1));
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id1"
LINE 1: id1 := (SELECT id FROM "CENZANO_Conceptos" WHERE codigo ...
        ^
QUERY:  id1 := (SELECT id FROM "CENZANO_Conceptos" WHERE codigo = 'CENZANO')
```

--second attepm

```
 EXECUTE FORMAT ('SELECT %I.id INTO id1 FROM %I WHERE mycolumn = %s', tablecode||'_Conceptos',tablecode||'_Conceptos',quote_literal(string1));

END;
......
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  EXECUTE of SELECT ... INTO is not implemented
HINT:  You might want to use EXECUTE ... INTO or EXECUTE CREATE TABLE ... AS instead.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INTO`:

```
EXECUTE FORMAT('(SELECT id FROM %I WHERE mycolumn = %s)'
                , tablecode||'_Conceptos', quote_literal(string1)) INTO id1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. I have a bunch of functions where I must to add the table like argument and it's being a headache for me ;-)